# Convert HRTFs in MAT format to SOFA format

Tags: matlab, acoustics

I have a dataset with HRTFs in .mat format, and I need to convert to different formats: .ascii_hrtf, .sofa and .daff.

I'm currently trying to convert to the SOFA format, and my idea is to load a general sofa file using the SOFAtoolbox and then replace the Data.IR with the HRTFs I have, but the dimensions do not match.
This doesn't seem to be an accurate approach, though.

```
%% Load HRTFs

% Start SOFA
SOFAstart;

load('C:\folder\hrtf_el0.mat');  % This gives me hrtfl and hrtfr

% Create a general SOFA structure
conventions='General';
disp(['Creating SOFA file with ' conventions 'conventions...']);
Obj = SOFAgetConventions(conventions);

LR = cat(4, hrtfl, hrtfr);

%% Update the ir data in the sofa file with the hrtfs
Obj.Data.IR = LR;
Obj.Data.SamplingRate = 48000;

%% Update dimensions
Obj=SOFAupdateDimensions(Obj);
```